# None of my servers are working on Fedora Server 23

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, firewall, minecraft

I currently am trying to use a Dell PowerEdge server with Fedora 23 Server as a minecraft server and a web server. For a while, my friend was using it to host his minecraft server on port 25565, and it worked completely fine after letting it through the firewall. When I try to connect to a server on port 25566 after letting it through the firewall, I can't connect. Even after disabling the firewall entirely, it doesn't work. My client can't connect to the server, and no connections come up in the server log.

The same goes for the web server: with both Apache and Nginx my web browser gives a time out error.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you disable the firewall? What else has changed in the "for a while?"

Comment: Nothing has changed in that time, and i disabled it with "systemctl disable firewalld" since that's what it says on the wiki.

Comment: Did you also do "systemctl stop firewalld" (or reboot)?

Comment: I recommend not disabling the firewall and instead adding a rule, by the way. But for diagnostic purposes.....

Comment: Stopping it finally worked, but what do you mean by rule? do you mean adding a port to one of the zones?

Comment: It finally started working after i figured out how to do a complete reload.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by adding a rule.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it sounds like you *disabled* firewalld, which prevents it from starting on boot, but didn't actually *stop* the currently running instance. This is a kind of jargony distinction, but it's a useful one — the state of the current system isn't necessarily the same as what you want when you next boot.

Also, note that with systemd, "disable" means "don't start on boot", but for some services, other events (like a message from some other service or hotplugging some hardware) could still activate them. To *completely* turn off a service, use `systemctl mask service`.

And, finally, I really recommend opening just the specific port you need to serve out rather than disabling the firewall. There isn't a lot more specific risk (since no services should be configured to listen without being explicitly enabled), but it's a good practice to get into.